# OnChange Caluclations With PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an order form and once a quantity is input into the text box I want the tax and total to update appropriately.  How is this done with php, or is this a javascript function that would need to be called?  Just for example sake, let's say that the tax would be .3%

**What I am after:**
1) OnChange() of txtitem1qty populate the tax (txtitem1tax)
2) OnChange() of txtitem1qty populate the total (txtitemtotalprice)

This is the code that I have thus far that populates my order table

```
<html>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <div id="Form1" runat="server">
        <table id="table1" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Tax</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="item1">Item 1</label></td>
                <td><label for="lblitem1price">$25.00</label></td>
                <td><input  type="text" name="txtitem1qty" value="0" maxlength="10" size="3"></td>
                <td><input  type ="text" name="txtitem1tax" maxlength="10" size="3" readonly></td>
                <td><input  type="text" name="txtitem1totalprice" maxlength="10" size="3" readonly></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to read about AJAX. You can't call PHP (server-side technology) directly from HTML or JavaScript (client-side).

Comment: @EdCottrell - will do, thank you for the starting point.

Comment: @SalathielGenèse - how would one use a datalist?

Comment: I went off from office saturday, it's comming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a example with the solution for you:

I made some necessary changes in your html, included "ids":

//html file

```
<tr>
                <td><label for="item1">Item 1</label></td>
                <td><label for="lblitem1price">$25.00</label></td>
                <td><input  type="text" id="item_1_qty" name="txtitem1qty" value="0" maxlength="10" size="3"></td>
                <td><input  type ="text" id="item_1_tax" name="txtitem1tax" maxlength="10" size="3" readonly></td>
                <td><input  type="text" id="item_1_totalprice" name="txtitem1totalprice" maxlength="10" size="3" readonly></td>
            </tr>
```

javascript in the html file:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function calculate(el){
        var quantity = el.val();
        var id = el.attr("id").replace("item_","").replace("_qty","");
        var data = {quantity: quantity,id:id};
        var targetTax = $("#item_"+id+"_tax");
        var targetTotalPrice = $("#item_"+id+"_totalprice");
        $.post("sandbox.php",data,function(response){
           response = JSON.parse(response);
            targetTax.val(response.tax);
            targetTotalPrice.val(response.totalprice);
        });
    }
    var qty = $("#item_1_qty");
    qty.on("keyup",function(){
        calculate($(this));
    });

</script>
```

my file is called sandbox, but can rename to calculate.php;

//sandbox.php

```
<?php

//The best way is that the data is in a database
$items = array(
    array("id"=> 1, "label"=> "Item1","value"=>25.0)
);

$tax = 0.3;
$id = isset($_POST['id'])?$_POST['id']:0;
if(!is_numeric($id)){
    $id = 0;
}
$quantity = isset($_POST['quantity'])?$_POST['quantity']:1;
if(!is_numeric($quantity)){
    $quantity = 1;
}
$finalValue = 0;
$currentItem = null;

foreach($items as $item){
    if($item["id"] == $id){
          $currentItem = $item;
    }
}

if($currentItem != null){
    $finalValue = $quantity * $currentItem["value"];
    $finalValue = ($finalValue * $tax) + $finalValue;
}

$return = array(
    'quantity' => $quantity,
    'tax' => $tax,
    'totalprice' => $finalValue
);

print json_encode($return);
```

**UPDATE:**
Finding the product in database, is only an example that you can apply:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'demo');
if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
$sql = "SELECT p.id,p.value FROM Products p WHERE p.id = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
/* execute prepared statement */
$stmt->execute();
/* close statement and connection */
$stmt->close();

if(!$result = $stmt->get_result()){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}

//$items = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$currentItem = $result->fetch_array();

$tax = 0.3;
$id = isset($_POST['id'])?$_POST['id']:0;
if(!is_numeric($id)){
    $id = 0;
}
$quantity = isset($_POST['quantity'])?$_POST['quantity']:1;
if(!is_numeric($quantity)){
    $quantity = 1;
}
$finalValue = 0;


if($currentItem != null){
    $finalValue = $quantity * $currentItem["value"];
    $finalValue = ($finalValue * $tax) + $finalValue;
}

$return = array(
    'quantity' => $quantity,
    'tax' => $tax,
    'totalprice' => $finalValue
);

print json_encode($return);
```

Comment: How would I store the label from your sandbox.php file in a database?  Just add a field to my table called label and insert that data?

Comment: It also seems that you are hard coding a value of $25.0 - would there be a way to pass the value from the text box of label for="lblitem1price"

Comment: 1) The $data array only represents one return of query in database. I believe that you already have the table in your database, the main thing here is the 'ID', in my example, the id of product are in attribute id of html elements. Because this I don't think that is really necessary include a new column for label. 
2) The value need be in you database, for security, only two parameters are sended to php, the ID and QUANTITY, with the id you can find the product in your database and retrieve the value for execute the calc. The HTML being only for show the results.